# EC2 Postfix custom email domain

Tags: amazon-ec2, postfix-mta

I have configured the EC2 and Postfix with domain somedomain.com, and hostname mail.somedomain.com.

The system now can send, and receive email correctly, with just a problem.

When I reply email using the 'mail' command to my Gmail, the sent email has sender address "root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal" instead of "root@somedomain.com". This long domain name can not be replied by my Gmail account.

Thanks.

Harry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved by using the domain name generic mapping.

http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic

The above link describes how to do it.

But it is a temporary solution that replaces the lengthy internal domain (ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxx.us-west-2.compute.internal) by mydomain.com for every OUTGOING email.

For local email, the system still uses the lengthy internal domain name (ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxx.us-west-2.compute.internal)

The problem is: postfix seems to have bypassed the $mydomain, $myorigin, $myhost variable I set in the /etc/main.cf file.

If anyone can solve it, I will greatly appreciate it.

Harry